# angular: why import command can search dependency from the build 'dist' folder

Tags: angular

I'm starting using Angular7 in a new project. This project consists of two parts: a shared component library and an example page for the library.

I was confused about one point in the project.

When I want to start the example page with `ng serve`, errors occur in the compilation process, the error is about following code:

```js
import { ComponentA } from "sharedlibrary" // can't find sharedlibrary
```

The `sharedlibrary` is the library we're developing. The error said it can't find the dependency of `sharedlibrary`. It makes senses since I didn't install it.

And following the `readme` instructions I first build the library with `ng build` which generating the `dist` output folder as expected.

Then I run `ng serve` to start the project, then the above mentioned error doesn't occur anymore.

I checked the line of code shown above, with vscode, it shows that

```js
import { ComponentA } from "sharedlibrary" // the sharedlibrary is the build package in the dist folder
```

I was confused about this point. How does this work? Why `import` command can search dependency in the `dist` folder?

Comment: it is in your angular.json file. there is sharedlibrary project (section "projects") and angular look at it to find your library which you try to import

Comment: Can you explain more, which setting in detail inside the angular.json do this? As far as I know, angular.json is config file for angular cli.

Comment: sorry, of course it is typescript, not angular. so config inside tsconfig.json. there is a path property with library name and path to it. here is the doc which explain it https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#building-and-rebuilding-your-library `When you build your own library, it has to find the mapping in your tsconfig paths`

Comment: ok, i find it. thank you